# Centos apache virtual hosts definition

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

*Please excuse me if my logic is flawed as I am really new to Centos.*

I know I can define multiple virtual hosts in my ***httpd.conf*** file.
But what I would like is to define virtual hosts in individual files as I am used to doing under Ubuntu.
In Ubuntu, my virtual hosts are defined in files under my **/etc/apache2/sites-available** and individually enabled ... but I can't find a similar structure & system under Centos.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include) should help you:

> Include Directive
>
> This directive allows inclusion of other configuration files from
>   within the server configuration files.
>
> Shell-style (fnmatch()) wildcard characters can be used to include
>   several files at once, in alphabetical order. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> Examples:
>
> Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.conf
>
> Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/vhosts/*.conf